# How to Make form responsive on sidebar collapse?

Tags: jquery

I have a bootstrap page with collapsible sidebar and Form. My Collapsible sidebar is working properly but i don't know how to make responsive my contact form on sidebar collapse.

My requirement is: When sidebar collapse, my form on page should properly display with screen size.

Here is My Code:

```
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });

  $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
var icon = $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon")
    if (icon.hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-right'))
         icon.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').addClass("glyphicon-chevron-left");
   else
      icon.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-left').addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");

 $('#menu ul').hide();
  });

function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul').hide();
  $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
  //$('#menu ul:first').show();
  $('#menu li a').click(
  function() {
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
  return false;
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
   $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
   checkElement.slideDown('normal');
   return false;
            }
         }
       );
     }
   $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Dashboard</a>
        <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li><a href="#">link1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">link2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Shortcut</a>
        <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>link1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>link2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Events</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x "></i></span>About</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Services</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /#sidebar-scroll -->
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 -->



              <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-8 '>-->

                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-2'>
                            <form role="form" id="contact_form">
                              <center>  <h3> Contact Form</h3></center>

                                <h3><small>Please Fill your Information Here</small></h3><br>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <img src="//placehold.it/40" class="avatar img-rounded" alt="avatar">
                                                <h6>Upload Photo</h6>
                                                <input type="file" class="form-control" title= "browse" data-input="false"  tabindex="1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input required type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg"  placeholder="First Name"  tabindex="2">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="3">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
                                                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" data-provide="datepicker" />-->
                                                <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birth_date" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" data-provide="datepicker" tabindex="4">
                                            </div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="h:mm PM" tabindex="5">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="fathername" id="father_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Father Name" tabindex="1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="mothername" id="mother_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Mother Name" tabindex="2">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!--<input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Display Name" tabindex="3">-->
                                    <textarea class="form-control input-md" id="address" rows="3" cols="70" placeholder="Address" tabindex="6"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" tabindex="7">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="City" tabindex="8">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="State" tabindex="9">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Pin Code." tabindex="10">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Mobile No." tabindex="11">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" tabindex="12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS :

```
  html,
  body{
 /*background: #f3efe0;*/
 /*background-color: #f3efe0;*/
 position: relative;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
/*background: url("../img/img/blue.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;*/
/*-webkit-background-size: cover;*/
/*-moz-background-size: cover;*/
/*-o-background-size: cover;*/
/*background-size: cover;*/
 }


#wrapper {
 margin-top: 51px;
  padding-left: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

 #wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
 }


#wrapper.toggled #menu-toggle span:before {content:'\2212'}


  #sidebar-wrapper {
     z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0; /* disini agar ketika di kecilkan tidak hilang semua default 0*/
   height: 100%;
   margin-left: -250px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
   }
   #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
   width: 250px;
    }

   #page-content-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 15px;
    }

   #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
     position: absolute;
     margin-right: -250px;
    }
 .fixed-brand{
    width: auto;
  }
   /* Sidebar Styles */

   .sidebar-nav {
   position: absolute;
   /*top: 50px;*/
   width: 250px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   margin-top: 2px;
  }

 .sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
   }

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
     color: #999999;
  }

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-left: red 2px solid;
  }

 .sidebar-nav li a:active,
 .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
   height: 65px;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 60px;
  }

 .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
  }

 .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
  }
 .no-margin{
   margin:0;
  }

 @media (min-width:768px) {
   #wrapper {
    padding-left: 42px;

  }
 .fixed-brand{
    width: 250px;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 54px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper:hover {
    width: 250px;

}


#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}
#wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}
/*#wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper:hover {*/
    /*width: 250px;*/
/*}*/

#page-content-wrapper {
    /*top:20px;*/
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 250px;

}
#wrapper.toggled-2 #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
   }
}


 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    color: white;
  }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(118, 94, 224, 0.3);
   border-radius: 10px;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 10px;
   /*-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
   background-color: gray;

  }




#toggle24{
   margin-right: 30%;
 }


.container {
  /*margin-left: 50%;*/
  }
```

Does anyone know how to do this :  When sidebar collapse, my form on page should properly display with screen size.

Here is my : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w50sdwyr/)

Comment: What do you mean by: "it should  properly display with screen size"...? Do you mean you want the form to be responsive to the user's current browser width? Why are you not using [Bootstrap's basic form elements](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)? Also, please only post the relevant javascript, markup, and css.

Comment: could you tell us which side bar your talking about in your jdfiddle ?

Comment: hi dreamweiver sidebar collapse with chevron icon which placed beside   sidebar..